# 'gnome-control-center' disappears on Ubuntu 18.10 after repostioning Ubuntu dock

Tags: 18.10, ubuntu-dock, gnome-control-center

When I change the position of the sidebar (dock), the 'Settings' window disappears from the screen and never shows up again.

The process starts to run when you click on the setting icon or run the command `gnome-control-center`, but the window does not show up at all.

What should I do?